# C++ xpcom components compile success but can not access by contract id

Tags: c++, macos, firefox, mozilla, xpcom

C++ xpcom components compile success but can not access by contract id
Error message:

```
TypeError: Components.classes["@cozmixng.org/xpcom-sample/Calc;1"] is undefined
```

I check out the xpcom-test source code from github,make some changes to compile on Mac OSX,
the myCalcModule.cpp

```
#include "mozilla/ModuleUtils.h"
#include "nsIClassInfoImpl.h"

#include "myCalc.h"

NS_GENERIC_FACTORY_CONSTRUCTOR(myCalc)

NS_DEFINE_NAMED_CID(MY_CALC_CID);

static const mozilla::Module::CIDEntry kCalcCIDs[] = {
    { &kMY_CALC_CID, false, NULL, myCalcConstructor },
    { NULL }
};
static const mozilla::Module::ContractIDEntry kCalcContracts[] = {
{ MY_CALC_CONTRACT_ID, &kMY_CALC_CID },
{ NULL }
};

static const mozilla::Module::CategoryEntry kCalcCategories[] = {
{ "my-category", "my-key", MY_CALC_CONTRACT_ID },
{ NULL }
};

static const mozilla::Module kCalcModule = {
mozilla::Module::kVersion,
kCalcCIDs,
kCalcContracts,
kCalcCategories
};

NSMODULE_DEFN(myCalcModule) = &kCalcModule;
```

in this code,export the module to dynamic library, call it in js

```
obj = Components.classes['@cozmixng.org/xpcom-
sample/Calc;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.myICalc);
```

use XPCOMViewer, can not fine the `@cozmixng.org/xpcom-sample/Calc;1` class!
The whole package in here  http://www.goseas.us/xpcom-test2.tar.gz!

Comment: Binary components will [only work with the same major version of the app](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/7586c29906b5/xpcom/components/nsNativeComponentLoader.cpp#l188) that it was compiled against. Did you compile your code using the same version of XulRunner SDK/Firefox source as the Firefox binary you're later trying to load your component into? Usually if the version mismatches and error gets logged to the error console...

Comment: Thank you very much! i fix just add <em:unpack>true</em:unpack> in the install.rdf,because firefox can not load a .so/.dll from JARs file       107     if (aFile.IsZip()) {

   108         NS_ERROR("Binary components cannot be loaded from JARs");

   109         return nullptr;

   110     }